# Nome da semana incompleto no retorno do strftime

Tags: php, data, localização

Estou tentando imprimir o dia da semana, de acordo com um determinado timestamp, com a função `strftime`.

Eu estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

echo strftime('%A', strtotime('now'));
```

Eu esperava o resultado `quinta-feira`, porém me é retornado `quinta`.

Porque aconteceu isso? O resultado não deveria ser o `quinta-feira`?

Eu estou usando o `Ubuntu`, com o `PHP 5.5.9-1 ubuntu 4.11`

Estou utilizando o Laravel 4 e esse problema ocorre no objeto `Carbon\Carbon`.

Exemplo:

```
#filters.php
App::before(function ()
{
     setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
});

#view qualquer
$usuario->created_at->formatLocalized('%A'); // quinta
```

**Observação**: Não quero usar um `array` com a lista de todos dos dias da semana  (obrigado)

Comment: Antes de publicar como resposta veja se isto lhe atende: http://www.tiagomatos.com/blog/dia-da-semana-mes-e-ano-em-portugues-utilizando-php sei que não que usar array mas a solução me parece bem simples

Comment: Não quero fazer assim. Estou usando o Laravel 4. E tenho que retornar isso através do object `Carbon\Carbon`, através da função formatLocalized. Não posso criar "métodos alterativos".

Comment: Entendo estou aprendo CakePHP e ele também é bem xaropi

Comment: Tenho uma pequena impressão que isso é configuração do `Ubuntu`. A minha data retorna `Quinta` extamente como no sistema operacional

Comment: não como dar uma concatenada ou editar o valor deste objeto com o valor do array de dias da semana?

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas acredito que nenhuma linguagem retorne a data com o sufixo `feira`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PHP retira as informações do locale do sistema operacional onde ele esta sendo executado. Como descrito na documentação:

> Nota: O valor de retorno de setlocale() depende do sistema no qual o
>   PHP esta sendo executado. Ele retorna exatamente o que a função
>   setlocale do sistema retorna.

Então se o sistema operacional exibir os dias da semana sem o "-feira" as datas exibidas pelo locale serão assim.

Utilizando seu próprio exemplo:

```
<?php
//teste.php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
echo strftime('%A', strtotime('now'));
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Quando eu executo esse script:

```
adirkuhn: ~ $ php teste.php 
quinta
```

---

Certo, então comparando com meu sistema operacional.
Primeiro no locale atual (inglês):

```
adirkuhn: ~ $ date +%A
Thursday
```

E agora com o locale em pt_BR:

```
adirkuhn: ~ $ LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF8 date +%A
quinta
```

---

Então você tem duas opções ou adiciona o "-feira" na mão com o PHP mesmo que é mais fácil.

Ou altera o arquivo de locale do sistema operacional.
Meu teste com o locale alterado:

```
...
LC_TIME
abday   "<U0044><U006F><U006D>";"<U0053><U0065><U0067>";/
        "<U0054><U0065><U0072>";"<U0051><U0075><U0061>";/
        "<U0051><U0075><U0069>";"<U0053><U0065><U0078>";/
        "<U0053><U00E1><U0062>"
day     "<U0064><U006F><U006D><U0069><U006E><U0067><U006F>";/
        "<U0073><U0065><U0067><U0075><U006E><U0064><U0061><U002D><U0066><U0065><U0069><U0072><U0061>";/
        "<U0074><U0065><U0072><U00E7><U0061><U002D><U0066><U0065><U0069><U0072><U0061>";/
        "<U0071><U0075><U0061><U0072><U0074><U0061><U002D><U0066><U0065><U0069><U0072><U0061>";/
        "<U0071><U0075><U0069><U006E><U0074><U0061><U002D><U0066><U0065><U0069><U0072><U0061>";/
        "<U0073><U0065><U0078><U0074><U0061><U002D><U0066><U0065><U0069><U0072><U0061>";/
        "<U0073><U00E1><U0062><U0061><U0064><U006F>"
...
```

Teste da data pelo sistema:

```
adirkuhn: ~ $ LC_TIME=pt_BR date +%A                                                                                  
quinta-feira
```

E agora o teste com o PHP:

```
adirkuhn: ~ $ php teste.php                                                                                           
quinta-feira
```

Comment: Vou marcar como resolvido, porque, já que é o sistema operacional, pelo menos eu posso falar com o pessoal do suporte técnico da hospedagem para eles alterarem (ou colocar na mão mesmo :\)

Answer (score 0):

Com datas a sempre várias soluções possíveis. Segue algumas:

```
$diasSemana = array('domingo', 'segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', ...);
echo $diasSemana[strftime('%w', strtotime('now')];
```

---

```
$now = strtotime('now');
echo strftime('%A', $now);

$decimalDiaSemana = strftime('%w', $now);
if ($decimalDiaSemana > 0 && $decimalDiaSemana < 6) {
    echo '-feira';
}
```

---

```
$now = strtotime('now');
$sufixo = array('', '-feira', '-feira', '-feira', '-feira', '-feira', '');
echo strftime('%A', $now) . $sufixo[strftime('%w', $now);
```

Comment: Se for para fazer com array, eu prefiro fazer assim `echo preg_replace('/^(segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta)$/i', '$1-feira', strftime('%A', strtotime('now')));`